# How to find values that aren't 100% duplicated?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a list of people getting aid from my organization.

Some register their names with different spelling or different order.

Here is an example

```
**Names**                       **ID**
Ahmed mohammed Saleh            3576158946          Personal ID  
Waleed Khalid Ali               5478698645          Personal ID
Fatima Nader Aljalal            4684325986          Personal ID
Hussan Huessien Ahmed           778569              Family ID
*Ahmed Mohamed Salah*           698745              Family ID
*Waleed Ali Khalid*             No ID
```

The last two in the list have registered twice.

My data has 4000 rows and I have to find the partial duplicates.

Comment: It's not so easy, you must define spelling checker, you must define which one is the wrong spelling and which one is the correct.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in "find duplicates" option in Excel? It would highlight the duplicates, so anything not highlighted would be not duplicates... But in the end, if they are spelled differently, then they are not duplicates by definition.

Comment: There are two problems. One is juxtaposition like *Waleed Khalid Ali* and *Waleed Ali Khaled*. For these you need to establish rules for which you need to flag for humans. For example, highlight "if first is the same and second and third are identical". The other is spelling. "M*h*m*d" can identify *Mohammed* or *Mohamed* or *mohamad* using Regix. Both systems need to be applied parallel to each other.

Comment: You may make some progress by treating names as a collection of characters.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011?

Answer (score 2):

One way to reduce the difficulty of the task is to hash the names to a sorted string of lowercase characters with duplicate characters, spaces and vowels removed.  You could then compare the hashed names to determine similarity.  In the example below we are fortunate that we get exact matches but it would not be impossible to write a further function that checked if the hashed names differed by one, two or more characters, and in fact that the original names were a reasonable match.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type State

    CharArray As Variant

End Type

Private s As State


Public Sub test()

    Initialise
    Debug.Print "Ahmed mohammed Saleh", ConvertNameToHash("Ahmed mohammed Saleh")
    Debug.Print "Ahmed Mohamed Salah", ConvertNameToHash("Ahmed Mohamed Salah")
    Debug.Print "Waleed Khalid Ali", ConvertNameToHash("Waleed Khalid Ali")
    Debug.Print "Waleed Ali Khalid", ConvertNameToHash("Waleed Ali Khalid")
End Sub

Public Sub Initialise()

    s.CharArray = Split("b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z", ",")

End Sub

Public Function ConvertNameToHash(ByVal ipName As String) As String

    Dim myChars As String
    Dim myName As String 

    myName = LCase$(ipName)
    Dim myChar As Variant
    For Each myChar In s.CharArray

        If InStr(myName, myChar) > 0 Then

            myChars = myChars & myChar

        End If

    Next

    ConvertNameToHash = myChars

End Function
```

The output from the above code was

```
Ahmed mohammed Saleh        dhlms
Ahmed Mohamed Salah         dhlms
Waleed Khalid Ali           dhklw
Waleed Ali Khalid           dhklw
```